# Failed to connect. Is Docker running? (Vs Code)

Tags: 20.04, docker, visual-studio-code

I get this error in Ubuntu in vscode and I can't see my images in vscode.

I run `sudo docker ps -a` and everything is OK on terminal!

What should I do to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it about `sudo`?

Comment: It is highly plausible that it's about `sudo`. You shouldn't set up docker to require `sudo`. Other than being a security problem, your IDE which doesn't run using sudo will not be able to access and use any docker command. Internally, it is most likely getting a permission denied error.

Comment: @Dan I should delete docker and install it in another way?

Comment: In theory, no. It is fixable. You can try following this doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/ on how to not require `sudo`. And then see if is enough (In short, you need to your user to the docker group and fix some permissions).